# Is there any conflict between using one CDN over another CDN?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, azure-cdn, content-delivery-network

A few years ago I build a web site hosted in Azure Static Websites then associate my domain using **CloudFlare** and all works good!

... But then I saw this new feature called **Azure CDN** a Microsoft Azure Content Delivery Network I create a new **CDN** endpoint and replace the origin hostname `xxx.web.core.windows.net` with the Azure **CDN** endpoint `xxx.azureedge.net` in CloudFlare.

Question... Is this bad for performance? Is there any conflict between Azure CDN and CloudFlare CDN? or just don't matter and don't help on anything...

Is there any conflict between using one CDN over another CDN in general?

*Thanks in advance...*

Comment: Are the records orange in Cloudflare? If so, the user will receive their copy from the nearest Cloudflare node, which in turn retrieve it when the cache expire from the nearest Azure CDN. There isn't a conflict, it's just the Azure is barely used in that case

Comment: Yes! are orange. You mean that in that case we would be wasting Azure CDN? Thank you so much @Martheen

Comment: Kinda, depending on whether you're being charged more for Azure CDN traffic vs direct traffic

Comment: I get it! Thank you @Martheen :)